# How can I split a tibble or data.frame that only has one column into four columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a tibble that I'm trying to separate into multiple columns:

[image]

The tibble only has one column and should look like the right side of the image when done.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example instead of images.  Try with `matrix(data$col, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `matrix` (assuming that the length of column is a multiple of 4)

```
matrix(data$col1, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)
```